# Get count of rows between two date column

Tags: mysql

I have added below my database table. in which i have two columns start and end time

```
Record_id |     userid| parent_id| start time          | end time            | 
        1 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:57:45 | 2018-08-15 23:57:55 |
        2 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:58:03 | 2018-08-15 23:58:22 |
        3 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:58:16 | 2018-08-15 23:59:05 |
        4 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:58:24 | 2018-08-16 00:33:35 |
        5 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:58:24 | 2018-08-15 23:58:29 |
        6 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:58:31 | 2018-08-15 23:58:32 |
        7 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:58:52 | 2018-08-15 23:59:00 |
        8 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:59:16 | 2018-08-16 00:00:05 |
        9 |        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:59:24 | 2018-08-15 23:59:32 |
        10|        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:59:27 | 2018-08-16 00:00:03 |
        11|        53 |       10 | 2018-08-15 23:59:43 | 2018-08-16 00:21:38 |
    +-----+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Output :

```
Date                | Count | user_id | parent_id | Record 
2018-08-15 23:58:00 | 1     | 53      | 0         |   1
2018-08-15 23:58:00 | 1     | 0       | 10        |   1
2018-08-15 23:59:00 | 6     | 53      | 0         |   2,3,4,5,6,7  
2018-08-15 23:59:00 | 6     | 0       | 10        |   2,3,4,5,6,7
2018-08-16 00:00:00 | 6     | 53      | 0         |   3,4,8,9,10,11
2018-08-16 00:00:00 | 6     | 0       | 10        |   3,4,8,9,10,11
2018-08-16 00:01:00 | 4     | 53      | 0         |   4,8,10,11
2018-08-16 00:01:00 | 4     | 0       | 10        |   4,8,10,11
```

Result Explanation :

First column (Date): DateTime,
Second column (Count): How many records available in the table on a particular DateTime.

Here we can see that in time: 2018-08-15 23:58:00 only record_id =1 is available. Means record_id=1 have start_time is must be greater than 2018-08-15 23:57:00 and it have end_time is must be less than or equal to 2018-08-15 23:58:00.

Suppose: Record_id =4 which have start_time is 2018-08-15 23:58:24 and end_time is 2018-08-16 00:33:35. 
So this record will be calculated every time from 2018-08-15 23:59:00(start_time is greater than 2018-08-15 23:58:00) to 2018-08-16 00:34:00(end_time is less than or equal to 2018-08-16 00:34:00).

Note :

1. If start time is 2018-08-15 12:12:01 to and end_time is <= 2018-08-15 12:13:00 then record will be consider into 2018-08-15 12:13:00. so this way 
   does not calculate record into multiple outputs
2. Expect count for a particular minute for particular user_id and parent_id
3. In Output, last column(record) is using only added for a better explanation /understanding.

Comment: Are userid and parent relevant to this problem?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Nope, Problem is i don't know how can i calculate count of records for particular user_id and parent_id based on start_time and end_time

Comment: @Ash : In this query i dont know how to do homework so i didn't add any code.Would you like to guide me ?

Comment: 1. take your start date in loop. 2. pass it to query & get the count for the perticular time. 3.add that selected count result into array & increase your start time by 1 minute & also check if start_time < end_time  4. at the end you will get the array with every minute

Comment: @Ash: Is it possible to get the result using only MySQL query. Because as per your explanation seems like to develop the script.

Comment: Script is required....

Comment: ...or do it without a script

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks for reply.But i dont know how to do without script.

Comment: I don't understand this result: `2018-08-15 23:58:00 | 1     | 53      | 0         |   1`

Comment: 1.I have make seprate user_id and parent_id 
2. First column showing is datetime : It mean how many records were in table on this time.  second column is count : Count is based on time between start_time and end_time. If we check record_id =1 is only available when time is 2018-08-15 23:58:00.

Comment: @Strawberry : I have added result explanation in question.Please check and let me know,If still needs more explanation

Comment: Nope. I still don't get it. I cannot see how record 1 is available at 23:58

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178196/discussion-between-ankit-doshi-and-strawberry).